# How can find out a custom date ( with calendar format ) based on an input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem sounds like this:
For N people , input their names and birthday dates. Based on this information, using substitute, create a custom message like:
"Hey ... ! There are ... more days until your birthday, when you will turn ... years old. A trip awaits you in the following days: ... - ... ( the period has to start 3 days before the birthday, and end 3 days after.)

For example:
n = 1 
Steve Potter
02.07.2000

output:
Hey Steve Potter ! There are 31 more days until your birthday, when you will turn 20 years old, A trip awaits you in the following days: 29.06.2020 - 05.07.2020

So far, I can't figure out more than that:

```
import string
import time

invitation = string.Template("Hey $name , There are $nrdays days until your birthday, when you will turn $years old. A trip awaits you in the following days: $start - $end")

n = int(input("Number of people:"))

for i in range(0, n):
    i_name = input("Name of the guest?")
    i_data = input("Birthday?")
    data = time.localtime()
    i_bdday = int(i_data[0] + i_data[1] )
    i_bdmonth = int(i_data[3] + i_data[4] )
    i_bdyear = int(i_data[6] + i_data[7] + i_data[8] + i_data[9] )
    i_years = data[0] - i_bdyear
    print ( invitation.substitute(name = i_name , years = i_years) )
```

How can I figure out how more days are there until a given date and also the interval I need?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime
```

Maybe you can find your own solution after reading it.

Comment: I managed to find out the number of days left until the birthday using

ii_data = time.strptime(i_data , '%d.%m.%Y')
i_days = abs ( data[7] - ii_data[7] )

And also now I don;t need the variables i_bdday, i_bdyear and i_bdmonth because I created the ii_data time struct which contains them. I still do not know how to replace the last 2 dates, but thank you !